# EL expression for class

Tags: java, jsp, el

I don't understand how to represent a `Class` in EL expressions.

I have an EL function that takes a class as parameter (namely an Enum class) to return possible enum values.

I want to invoke it as EL expression. E.g.  `${myTld:enumer(com.example.enums.MyEnum)}`

However:

- The above syntax passes null as argument
- Using `MyEnum.class` throws an exception such as the expression cannot be evaluated

How do I express a class in EL without possibly passing by its string representation?

#### The below works

```
<function>
    <description>
        Returns the list of enum values for the given enum class
    </description>
    <name>enumer</name>
    <function-class>com.example.Functions</function-class>
    <function-signature>List enumer(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
</function>

${tld:enumer('com.example.MyEnum')}
```

#### What I would like

```
    <function-signature>List enumer(java.lang.Class)</function-signature>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't represent a `Class` in plain EL. You can at most pass it through if it were a bean property like so `${myTld:enumer(bean.someEnumClass)}` returning `Class<? extends Enum>`, or `${myTld:enumer(bean.someEnum['class'])}` where `someEnum` is the actual `Enum`, but that's it. Passing around the class name as `String` is really your best bet.

If you're already on EL 3.0 (available on Servlet 3.1 containers like Tomcat 8, WildFly 8, etc), an alternative to your custom function is to just import it right away in JSP like below using the new EL 3.0 [`ImportHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ImportHandler.html) API:

```html
${pageContext.ELContext.importHandler.importClass('com.example.enums.MyEnum')}
```

The enum is then available by `${MyEnum}`.

```html
<c:forEach items="${MyEnum.values()}" var="myEnumValue">
    ${myEnumValue}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Alternatively, import the `${MyEnum}` globally via a servlet context listener like below:

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getJspApplicationContext(event.getServletContext()).addELContextListener(new ELContextListener() {
            @Override
            public void contextCreated(ELContextEvent event) {
                event.getELContext().getImportHandler().importClass(MyEnum.class.getName());
            }
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: The answer is correct and satisfying. I solved using a String and then Class.forName in the code behind

Answer (score 3):

I guess you wish to pass `Class` arguments to your function to improve performance by avoid parsing strings with `Class.forName()` each time... True?

If so, I think there is a way... If you know in advance the classes you will pass your function as arguments, use a `ServletContextListener` to put them into your application scope. This may look as follows:

```
@WebListener
public class MyEnumInitializer implements ServletContextListener {

  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    Map<String, Class<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("MyEnum1", MyEnum1.class);
    map.put("MyEnum2", MyEnum2.class);
    // etc.
    sce.getServletContext().addAttribute("myEnums", map);
  }

  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {}

}
```

If you are using a Servlet API version prior to 3.0, discard the `@WebListener` annotation above and declare the listener in your `web.xml` file as follows:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>mypackage.MyEnumListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Having your function that takes a `Class`, you could use it as follows:

```
${tld:enumer(myEnums['MyEnum1'])}
```

There is still a `String`-to-`Class` mapping, but it involves locating a `Class` object using a `String` key in a `HashMap`, which is faster than resolving the `Class` object using reflection.

Moreover, if you ever need to add to this `HashMap` a class you can't foresee as of initializing the application, you can still do it wherever you have access to your `ServletContext` (the `HashMap`isn't immutable). For example, in any method receiving an `HttpServletRequest` as a parameter:

```
public void aMethod(HttpServletRequest req, [other params]) {
  // ...
  Map<String, Class<?>> myEnums = (Map<String, Class<?>>) req.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("myEnums");
  if (!myEnums.containsKey("aNewEnum")) {
    myEnums.put("aNewEnum", NewEnum.class);
  }
  // ...
}
```

Cheers,

Jeff